# Convert/change JavaScript document to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For an assignment, I am required to code my site in pure JavaScript, then convert those same elements to jQuery.

I understand jQuery is just a style of JavaScript. But I don't understand how to change my elements in jQuery. I assumed it would be like switching my html into bootstrap but I see it isn't.

For example, this is my JavaScript code for a countdown clock. Do I just need to add a dollar sign instead of var? Please don't link me to a jQuery tutorial; as I am looking at some already, instead can you help me understand out how to reconcile the two.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("June 5, 2018 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = days + "d " +
      hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: a help: https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7307312
don't forget to import the jQuery to the document (https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: `$('#clock').html('Put your text here');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Any valid Javascript code is also valid in jQuery. Remember that jQuery is just a library on top of Javascript and not a *'style'* of it, which does a bunch of specialized stuff like DOM manipulation, AJAX requests etc.**

The `$` in the jQuery is the selector to select DOM elements like what we write `document.querySelector()` or `document.getElementById()` in vanilla Javascript.

The quintessential jQuery selector will allow you to select DOM elements using CSS selectors as follows:

```
$("#YourIDNameHere").click(){
//some event handling logic here
};
```

---

Firstly import jQuery into your application by using a CDN:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> 
 </script>
</head>
```

So you just need to rewrite the following code in a jQuery way.

```
let timeString = `${days} days ${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds`;

$("#clock").html = timeString;

// If the count down is finished, write some text
if (distance < 0) {
   clearInterval(x);
   $("#clock").html = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple.

Intead of using:

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
```

You just need to use the jquery equivalent, where "#clock" is the jquery selector:

```
$("#clock").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
```

Comment: And as a fellow said above, make sure to import the jquery library to your project

Answer (score 0):

variable declaration in javascript and jQuery will be same

it is when you access elements of DOM the syntax will change

you will either need to down load the jquery--.min.js from jquery.org or link to it in your html. Here I have downloaded 2.2.0 min js and used in my html page in `< head >` section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

then when accessing the elements you need to follow below syntax

to get values

```
$("#clock").html();
```

to set values

```
$("#clock").html("newvalue");
```

when to use .val() or .text() or .html() depends on the element you are accessing